# PHP MySQL valid query with like and visible

Tags: php, mysql

how to create a valid query to mysql database?

how to add `WHERE visible = 1` to this query

```
SELECT *
FROM photographs
WHERE caption like %colname% or caption_2 like %colname%
```

Comment: What do u mean by `colname`? its column name or your variable name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM photographs
WHERE caption LIKE '%colname%'
OR caption_2 LIKE '%colname%' 
AND visible = 1
```

Comment: Can you check column name as a pattern?

Answer (score -1):

I think I did something wrong in the code because something does not work:)
show me all result

```
mysql_select_db($database_Photo_con, $Photo_con);
$query_rsPhoto = sprintf("SELECT * FROM photographs WHERE caption LIKE %s OR caption_2 LIKE %s  AND visible = 1 ", GetSQLValueString("%" . $colname_rsPhoto . "%", "text"),GetSQLValueString("%" . $colname_rsPhoto . "%", "text"));
$query_limit_rsPhoto = sprintf("%s LIMIT %d, %d", $query_rsPhoto, $startRow_rsPhoto, $maxRows_rsPhoto);
$rsPhoto = mysql_query($query_limit_rsPhoto, $Photo_con) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rsPhoto = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsPhoto);
```